# How to calculate precision and recall in Keras

Tags: python, precision, keras, precision-recall

I am building a multi-class classifier with Keras 2.02 (with Tensorflow backend)，and I do not know how to calculate precision and recall in Keras. Please help me.

Comment: I noticed from this page: https://ja.ojit.com/so/tensorflow/3439045 that you were able to use non standard losses such as precision_recall_auc_loss() with Keras. I've tried but failed to reuse the code snippet you provide. Would it be possible to publish a more complete example code?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Python package [keras-metrics](https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/) could be useful for this (I'm the package's author).

```py
import keras
import keras_metrics

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", input_dim=2))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="sgd",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[keras_metrics.precision(), keras_metrics.recall()])
```

**UPDATE**: Starting with `Keras` version `2.3.0`, such metrics as precision, recall, etc. are provided within library distribution package.

The usage is the following:

```py
model.compile(optimizer="sgd",
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[keras.metrics.Precision(), keras.metrics.Recall()])
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that you are the author of this package, both in the interest of full disclosure of your affiliation, and to lend your answer more credibility.

Comment: @Dref360 says "As of Keras 2.0, precision and recall were removed from the master branch." -- so is this the metrics that have been removed, or can you still use keras_metric with Keras 2.0?

Comment: it gives precision and recall = 0.000 in Keras 2.2.2 and keras-metrics 0.0.5. I used the same code as above. But when I use the solution posted by @Christian, it return values.

Comment: @DrGeneral, could you, please, provide a model and the training data you use, so I could validate what's wrong with the implementation. I recall, there is a calculation issue with _Tensorflow_ backend with version ```<1.8.0```.

Comment: @YashaBubnov, ohh. I'm using tensorflow 1.5 and my model is a LSTM with sigmoid activation at the last layer. I'm glad to help you but I'm not allowed to share company's data. sorry :)

Comment: calling the `tf.global_variables_initializer` breaks everything including keras builtin accuracy either `K.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` or using `with`

Comment: Hi. How do you access these metrics?? I have them printing out which is nice, but I need them in separate variables. I've tried accessing them via dot syntax or through the history but no luck. Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

As of Keras 2.0, precision and recall were removed from the master branch. You will have to implement them yourself. Follow this guide to create custom metrics : [Here](https://keras.io/metrics/).

Precision and recall equation can be found [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

Or reuse the code from keras before it was removed [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/commit/a56b1a55182acf061b1eb2e2c86b48193a0e88f7).

There metrics were remove because they were batch-wise so the value may or may not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I reuse the code from keras before it was removed, I get 0 for both of precision and recall value. Why?

Comment: Why have they been removed?

Comment: Please make sure that your answer is useful even if the links break.

Comment: Explanation for removing can be found here, with a solution to compute it with a callback implementation: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794

Comment: Is it possible to adapt the code and compute the respective metrics across the whole dataset, i.e. train and test? I see there are some solutions provided in the github thread but I cannot tell if they are, again, batch-wise or across the entire dataset

Answer (score 7):

My answer is based on the [comment of Keras GH issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794#issuecomment-303683985). It calculates validation precision and recall at every epoch for a onehot-encoded classification task. Also please look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547402/how-to-calculate-f1-macro-in-keras) to see how it can be done with `keras.backend` functionality.

```py
import keras as keras
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

model = keras.models.Sequential()
# ...
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self._data = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        X_val, y_val = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
        y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(X_val))

        y_val = np.argmax(y_val, axis=1)
        y_predict = np.argmax(y_predict, axis=1)

        self._data.append({
            'val_recall': recall_score(y_val, y_predict),
            'val_precision': precision_score(y_val, y_predict),
        })
        return

    def get_data(self):
        return self._data


metrics = Metrics()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[metrics])
metrics.get_data()
```

Comment: Need to do `recall_score(y_val, y_predict, average=None)` and `precision_score(y_val, y_predict, average=None)` here. The default is `average=binary` and you'll get an error because this is multi-class classification.

Comment: Your code use an external reference of the object "model".

Comment: @EthanChen do you mean after I have the history I can access the same precision, recall, auc, and accuracy and store them in separate variables by doing `recall=recall_score(y_val, y_predict, average=None)`? Same with all 4 metrics? Says metrics is not defined even though I already have the import.

Answer (score 2):

Use Scikit Learn framework for this.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle=True)
pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
predicted = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)
report = classification_report(np.argmax(y_test, axis=1), predicted)
print(report)
```

[This blog](https://blog.plon.io/tutorials/cifar-10-classification-using-keras-tutorial/) is very useful.

Comment: This is something you do at the end. But to get these values for every epoch and see how they evolve?

Answer (score 2):

This thread is a little stale, but just in case it'll help someone landing here. If you are willing to upgrade to Keras v2.1.6, there has been a lot of work on getting stateful metrics to work though there seems to be more work that is being done (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9446).

Anyway, I found the best way to integrate precision/recall was using the custom metric that subclasses `Layer`, shown by example in [BinaryTruePositives](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/tests/keras/metrics_test.py#L114).

For recall, this would look like:

```
class Recall(keras.layers.Layer):
    """Stateful Metric to count the total recall over all batches.

    Assumes predictions and targets of shape `(samples, 1)`.

    # Arguments
        name: String, name for the metric.
    """

    def __init__(self, name='recall', **kwargs):
        super(Recall, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.stateful = True

        self.recall = K.variable(value=0.0, dtype='float32')
        self.true_positives = K.variable(value=0, dtype='int32')
        self.false_negatives = K.variable(value=0, dtype='int32')
    def reset_states(self):
        K.set_value(self.recall, 0.0)
        K.set_value(self.true_positives, 0)
        K.set_value(self.false_negatives, 0)

    def __call__(self, y_true, y_pred):
        """Computes the number of true positives in a batch.

        # Arguments
            y_true: Tensor, batch_wise labels
            y_pred: Tensor, batch_wise predictions

        # Returns
            The total number of true positives seen this epoch at the
                completion of the batch.
        """
        y_true = K.cast(y_true, 'int32')
        y_pred = K.cast(K.round(y_pred), 'int32')

        # False negative calculations
        y_true = K.cast(y_true, 'int32')
        y_pred = K.cast(K.round(y_pred), 'int32')
        false_neg = K.cast(K.sum(K.cast(K.greater(y_pred, y_true), 'int32')), 'int32')
        current_false_neg = self.false_negatives * 1
        self.add_update(K.update_add(self.false_negatives,
                                     false_neg),
                        inputs=[y_true, y_pred])
        # True positive  calculations
        correct_preds = K.cast(K.equal(y_pred, y_true), 'int32')
        true_pos = K.cast(K.sum(correct_preds * y_true), 'int32')
        current_true_pos = self.true_positives * 1
        self.add_update(K.update_add(self.true_positives,
                                     true_pos),
                        inputs=[y_true, y_pred])
        # Combine
        recall = (K.cast(self.true_positives, 'float32') / (K.cast(self.true_positives, 'float32') + K.cast(self.false_negatives, 'float32') + K.cast(K.epsilon(), 'float32')))
        self.add_update(K.update(self.recall,
                                     recall),
                        inputs=[y_true, y_pred])

        return recall
```