# How to calculate F1 Macro in Keras?

Tags: keras

I've tried to use the code given from Keras before they're removed. Here's the code:

```py
def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision

def recall(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    return recall

def fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=1):
    if beta < 0:
        raise ValueError('The lowest choosable beta is zero (only precision).')

    # If there are no true positives, fix the F score at 0 like sklearn.
    if K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1))) == 0:
        return 0

    p = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    r = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    bb = beta ** 2
    fbeta_score = (1 + bb) * (p * r) / (bb * p + r + K.epsilon())
    return fbeta_score

def fmeasure(y_true, y_pred):
    return fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=1)
```

From what I saw, it seems like they use the correct formula. But, when I tried to use it as a metric in the training process, I got exactly equal output for val_accuracy, val_precision, val_recall, and val_fmeasure. I do believe that it might happen even if the formula correct, but I believe it is unlikely. Any explanation for this issue?

Comment: Are the output values identically zero?

Comment: Could you provide as a full code - with the `fit` and `compile` calls? Could you also provide more details about your data?

Comment: This is a known issue in Keras (See: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5400). Precision, Rcall, and F1-Score are being estimated in a batchwise fashon.

Comment: The best approach in my opinion is the one adopted in: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5400#issuecomment-282188692

Comment: There are 2 categories of label, 0 and 1. I use categorical_crossentropy and the last Dense layer is using softmax activation function. I tried to change the code to use binary_crossentropy and the last Dense layer using relu, and the precision, etc are working perfectly. I figure it is because of the function cannot be applied to tensor shaped data. Any suggestion?

Comment: I assume you do use 1-hot coding with categorical_crossentropy but not when using binary_crossentropy ?

Comment: Yes, i use one hot encoding. And i've tried to run the code with single batch tensor and it worked. I assume the code is having trouble with 3d tensor(with batch). Just a possibility. What do you think?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

since Keras 2.0 metrics f1, precision, and recall have been removed. The solution is to use a custom metric function:

```py
from keras import backend as K

def f1(y_true, y_pred):
    def recall(y_true, y_pred):
        """Recall metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of recall.

        Computes the recall, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many relevant items are selected.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
        recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
        return recall

    def precision(y_true, y_pred):
        """Precision metric.

        Only computes a batch-wise average of precision.

        Computes the precision, a metric for multi-label classification of
        how many selected items are relevant.
        """
        true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
        precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
        return precision
    precision = precision(y_true, y_pred)
    recall = recall(y_true, y_pred)
    return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer= "adam",
          metrics=[f1])
```

The return line of this function

```py
return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))
```

was modified by adding the constant epsilon, in order to avoid division by 0. Thus NaN will not be computed.

Comment: I tried this but it just return NaN (accuracy is 99%, but I got precision and recall, with this code, as 0%)

Comment: Figure it out the problem. My model is not prediction true values. Thank you, @Paddy.

Comment: Weird, I'm also getting a NaN value when evaluating the whole test set. However, when taking the top 5 samples, it correctly returns the f1 score.

Comment: Change `return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall))` to `return 2*((precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon()))` to fix NaN's

Comment: @RonakAgrawal , Even so, I have nan values .. !

Comment: @Minion perhaps, it has nothing to do with the metric function

Comment: is it ok for multi label classification with one hot encoded labels?

Comment: Can someone explain these two lines true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
        possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))

Comment: Does the above code work if y_true is one-hot encoded

Comment: @Nitin no it doesn't

Comment: It seems like this implementation calculates per-batch f1-score, not per-epoch, which is not useful.

Answer (score 31):

Using a Keras metric function is not the right way to calculate F1 or AUC or something like that.

The reason for this is that the metric function is called at each batch step at validation. That way the Keras system calculates an average on the batch results. And that is not the right F1 score.

Thats the reason why F1 score got removed from the metric functions in keras. See here:

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/a56b1a55182acf061b1eb2e2c86b48193a0e88f7
- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794

The right way to do this is to use a custom callback function in a way like this:

- https://github.com/PhilipMay/mltb#module-keras
- https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2

Answer (score 3):

This is a streaming custom f1_score metric that I made using subclassing. It works for TensorFlow 2.0 beta but I haven't tried it on other versions. What it's doing it keeping track of true positives, predicted positives, and all possible positives throughout the whole epoch and then calculating the f1 score at the end of the epoch. I think the other answers are only giving the f1 score for each batch which isn't really the best metric when we really want the f1 score of the all the data.

I got a raw unedited copy of Aurélien Geron new book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow 2.0 and highly recommend it. This is how I learned how to this f1 custom metric using sub-classes. It's hands down the most comprehensive TensorFlow book I've ever seen. TensorFlow is seriously a pain in the butt to learn and this guy lays down the coding groundwork to learn a lot.

FYI: In the Metrics, I had to put the parenthesis in f1_score() or else it wouldn't work.

pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

def create_f1():
    def f1_function(y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred_binary = tf.where(y_pred>=0.5, 1., 0.)
        tp = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * y_pred_binary)
        predicted_positives = tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_binary)
        possible_positives = tf.reduce_sum(y_true)
        return tp, predicted_positives, possible_positives
    return f1_function


class F1_score(keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs) # handles base args (e.g., dtype)
        self.f1_function = create_f1()
        self.tp_count = self.add_weight("tp_count", initializer="zeros")
        self.all_predicted_positives = self.add_weight('all_predicted_positives', initializer='zeros')
        self.all_possible_positives = self.add_weight('all_possible_positives', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred,sample_weight=None):
        tp, predicted_positives, possible_positives = self.f1_function(y_true, y_pred)
        self.tp_count.assign_add(tp)
        self.all_predicted_positives.assign_add(predicted_positives)
        self.all_possible_positives.assign_add(possible_positives)

    def result(self):
        precision = self.tp_count / self.all_predicted_positives
        recall = self.tp_count / self.all_possible_positives
        f1 = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall)
        return f1

X = np.random.random(size=(1000, 10))     
Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1000,))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=[X.shape[1], ]),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD', metrics=[F1_score()])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Diesche mentioned the main problem in implementing f1_score this way is that it is called at every batch step and leads to confusing results more than anything else.

I've been struggling some time with this issue but eventually worked my way around the problem by using a callback: at the end of an epoch the callback predicts on the data (in this case I chose to only apply it to my validation data) with the new model parameters and gives you coherent metrics evaluated on the whole epoch.

I'm using tensorflow-gpu (1.14.0) on python3

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from sklearn.metrics import  f1_score
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers



optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

class Metrics(Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, valid_data, true_outputs):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.model=model
        self.valid_data=valid_data    #the validation data I'm getting metrics on
        self.true_outputs=true_outputs    #the ground truth of my validation data
        self.steps=len(self.valid_data)


    def on_epoch_end(self, args,*kwargs):
        gen=generator(self.valid_data)     #generator yielding the validation data
        val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(gen, batch_size=1, verbose=0, steps=self.steps)))

        """
        The function from_proba_to_output is used to transform probabilities  
        into an understandable format by sklearn's f1_score function
        """
        val_predict=from_proba_to_output(val_predict, 0.5)
        _val_f1 = f1_score(self.true_outputs, val_predict)
        print ("val_f1: ", _val_f1, "   val_precision: ", _val_precision, "   _val_recall: ", _val_recall)
```

The function `from_proba_to_output` goes as follows:

```py
def from_proba_to_output(probabilities, threshold):
    outputs = np.copy(probabilities)
    for i in range(len(outputs)):

        if (float(outputs[i])) > threshold:
            outputs[i] = int(1)
        else:
            outputs[i] = int(0)
    return np.array(outputs)
```

I then train my model by referencing this metrics class in the callbacks part of fit_generator. I did not detail the implementation of my train_generator and valid_generator as these data generators are specific to the classification problem at hand and posting them would only bring confusion.

```py
    model.fit_generator(
train_generator, epochs=nbr_epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=valid_generator, callbacks=[Metrics(model, valid_data)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As what @Pedia has said in his comment above, `on_epoch_end`,as stated in the [github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5400](http://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5400) is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest this work-around

- install [keras_metrics](https://pypi.org/project/keras-metrics/) package by ybubnov
- call `model.fit(nb_epoch=1, ...)` inside a for loop taking advantage of the precision/recall metrics outputted after every epoch

Something like this:

```py
    for mini_batch in range(epochs):
        model_hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=1,
                            verbose=2, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

        precision = model_hist.history['val_precision'][0]
        recall = model_hist.history['val_recall'][0]
        f_score = (2.0 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
        print 'F1-SCORE {}'.format(f_score)
```

Comment: Deprecated according to its github page

Comment: According to their github all their metrics are now included in Keras as of 2.3.0.