# Calculating Fscore for each epoch using keras (not batch-wise)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Essence of this question:

***I'd like to find a proper way to calculate the Fscore for the validation and training data after each epoch (not batch-wise)***

For a binary classification task, I'd like to calculate the `Fscore` after each epoch using a simple `keras`  model. But how to calculate the `Fscore` seems quite the discussion.

I know `keras` works in batches and one way to calculate the fscore *for each batch* would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305384/10053244 (Fscore-calculation: `f1`).

The batch-wise calculation can be quite confusing and I prefer to calculate Fscore *after each epoch*. So just calling `history.history['f1']` or `history.history['val_f1']` does **not** do the trick, cause it shows the batch-wise fscores.

I figured one way is to save each model using the  `from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint` function:

1. Saving each model-weights after every epoch
2. Reloading the model and using `model.evaluate` ***or*** `model.predict`

**Edit:**

Using tensorflow backend, I decided to track `TruePositives`, `FalsePositives` and `FalseNegatives` (as umbreon29 suggested).
But now comes the fun part: **The results when reloading the model are different for the training data** (TP, FP, FN are different) *but not for the validation set!*

So a simple model storing the weights to rebuild each model and recalculate the TP,FN,TP (and finally the Fscore) looks like:

```
from keras.metrics import TruePositives, TrueNegatives, FalseNegatives, FalsePositives

## simple keras model
sequence_input = Input(shape=(input_dim,), dtype='float32')
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(sequence_input)
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[TruePositives(name='true_positives'),
                       TrueNegatives(name='true_negatives'),
                       FalseNegatives(name='false_negatives'),
                       FalsePositives(name='false_positives'),
                       f1])

# model checkpoints
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_f1:.2f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(savemodel,filepath), monitor='val_f1', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), epochs=epoch, batch_size=batch,
                    callbacks=[callbacks_list])

## Saving TP, FN, FP to calculate Fscore
tp.append(history.history['true_positives'])
fp.append(history.history['false_positives'])
fn.append(history.history['false_negatives'])

arr_train = np.stack((tp, fp, fn), axis=1)

## doing the same for tp_val, fp_val, fn_val 
[...]
arr_val = np.stack((tp_val, fp_val, fn_val), axis=1)

## following method just showes batch-wise fscores and shouldnt be used:
## f1_sc.append(history.history['f1'])
```

Reloading the model after each epoch to calculate the Fscores (The `predict` method with sklearn fscore metric  `from sklearn.metrics import f1_score` is equivalent to the calculating fscore metric from TP,FP, FN):

```
Fscore_val = []
fscorepredict_val_sklearn = []
Fscore_train = []
fscorepredict_train = []

## model_loads contains list of model-paths
for i in model_loads:
    ## rebuilding the model each time since only weights are stored
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(input_dim,), dtype='float32')
    preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(sequence_input)
    model = Model(sequence_input, preds)
    model.load_weights(i)
    
    # Compile model (required to make predictions)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam',
                  metrics=[TruePositives(name='true_positives'),
                           TrueNegatives(name='true_negatives'),
                           FalseNegatives(name='false_negatives'),
                           FalsePositives(name='false_positives'),
                           f1
                           ])    
    
    ### For Validation data
    ## using evaluate
    y_pred =  model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, verbose=0)
    Fscore_val.append(y_pred)  ## contains (loss,tp,fp,fn, f1-batchwise)
    
    ## using predict
    y_pred = model.predict(x_val)
    val_preds = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in y_pred]
    cm = f1_score(y_val, val_preds)
    fscorepredict_val_sklearn.append(cm)  ## equivalent to Fscore calculated from Fscore_vals tp,fp, fn


    ### For the training data
    y_pred =  model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0) 
    Fscore_train.append(y_pred) ## also contains (loss,tp,fp,fn, f1-batchwise)
    
    y_pred =  model.predict(x_train, verbose=0)  # gives probabilities
    train_preds = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in y_pred]
    cm = f1_score(y_train, train_preds)
    fscorepredict_train.append(cm)
```

Calculating the Fscore from the tp,fn, and fp using `Fscore_val`'s tp,fn,fp and comparing it to`fscorepredict_val_sklearn` is equivalent and identical to calculating it from `arr_val`.

***However,*** the number of tp,fn, and fp is different when comparing `Fscore_train` and `arr_train`. Therefore, I also arrive at different Fscores. The number of tp,fn,fp should be the same but they arent.. **Is this a bug?**

Which one should I trust? The `fscorepredict_train` seem actually more trustworthy, since they start above the "always guessing class 1"-Fscore (when recall=1). (`fscorepredict_train[0]=0.6784` vs `f_hist[0]=0.5736` vs always-guessing-class-1-fscore = 0.6751)

[*Note:* `Fscore_train[0] = [0.6853608025386962, 2220.0, 250.0, 111.0, 1993.0, 0.6730511784553528]` (loss,tp,tn,fp,fn) leading to fscore= 0.6784 , so Fscore from Fscore_train = fscorepredict_train ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I provide a custom callback that computes the score (in your case F1 from sklearn) on ALL the data at the end of the epoch (for train and optionally validation)

```
class F1History(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, train, validation=None):
        super(F1History, self).__init__()
        self.validation = validation
        self.train = train

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        logs['F1_score_train'] = float('-inf')
        X_train, y_train = self.train[0], self.train[1]
        y_pred = (self.model.predict(X_train).ravel()>0.5)+0
        score = f1_score(y_train, y_pred)       

        if (self.validation):
            logs['F1_score_val'] = float('-inf')
            X_valid, y_valid = self.validation[0], self.validation[1]
            y_val_pred = (self.model.predict(X_valid).ravel()>0.5)+0
            val_score = f1_score(y_valid, y_val_pred)
            logs['F1_score_train'] = np.round(score, 5)
            logs['F1_score_val'] = np.round(val_score, 5)
        else:
            logs['F1_score_train'] = np.round(score, 5)
```

here a dummy example:

```
x_train = np.random.uniform(0,1, (30,10))
y_train = np.random.randint(0,2, (30))

x_val = np.random.uniform(0,1, (20,10))
y_val = np.random.randint(0,2, (20))

sequence_input = Input(shape=(10,), dtype='float32')
preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='output')(sequence_input)
model = Model(sequence_input, preds)

es = EarlyStopping(patience=3, verbose=1, min_delta=0.001, monitor='F1_score_val', mode='max', restore_best_weights=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10, 
          callbacks=[F1History(train=(x_train,y_train),validation=(x_val,y_val)),es])
```

the output print:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 78ms/step - loss: 0.7453 - F1_score_train: 0.3478 - F1_score_val: 0.4762
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 57ms/step - loss: 0.7448 - F1_score_train: 0.3478 - F1_score_val: 0.4762
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 58ms/step - loss: 0.7444 - F1_score_train: 0.3478 - F1_score_val: 0.4762
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.7439Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 70ms/step - loss: 0.7439 - F1_score_train: 0.3478 - F1_score_val: 0.4762
```

I have TF 2.2 and works without problems, I hope this help