# Sklearn Metrics of precision, recall and FMeasure on Keras classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

I have a problem trying to compute precision, recall and FMeasure as part of the metrics for evaluating an LSTM text classifier implemented in Keras on Tensorflow. I'm aware that [these functions were removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076609/how-to-calculate-precision-and-recall-in-keras) from `Keras 2.02` metrics module.

```
# create the model
embedding_vector_length = 32
model = Sequential()
# load the dataset with word embedding but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vector_length, input_length=max_tweet_length)) 

model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
print(scores)

# print the classification report
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
predicted = model.predict(X_test)
report = classification_report(y_test, predicted)
print(report)
```

As an alternative I'm parsing the fitted model and predicted output as object into `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` however I keep getting the errors about the data types of the targets. The predicted output is of the `float32` format since I'm using the Sigmoid activation function, while the labels is a collection of text with binary levels of classification. I get the accuracy evaluation from the Keras metrics but the precison, recall, fmeasure evaluation is the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 1261, in precision_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 1025, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 81, in _check_targets
    "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets
```

Comment: The exception seems pretty straightforward. What are the types of the elements in each of `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, and `y_test`? It seems you might have a bunch of 0s and 1s and potentially some extraneous elements, too.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you did not find out what the output of `model.predict`. In fact, for your case (you used **binary_classification** there) you need to call `model.predict_classes` to match your class/label data `y`.