# Calculating precision, recall and F1 in Keras v2, am I doing it right?

Tags: python, keras, precision-recall, keras-2

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065484/getting-precision-recall-and-f1-score-per-class-in-keras) on how to obtain precision, recall and F1 scores in Keras v2, here is the method I'm using but the question is: am I doing it right?

First of all, F. Chollet [says](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794) he removed these three metrics from version 2 of Keras because they were batch-based and hence not reliable. I'm following an idea by [basque21](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794) using a Callback with method on_epoch_end, isn't this normally batch-independent since calculated at epoch end (= after all batches have finished)?

Here is the code I'm using. In the model.fit method I add the argument `callbacks=[metrics]` and I define a dictionary `myhistory` and a class `Metrics` as follows (code adapted from [basque21](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794)):

```
myhistory={}
myhistory['prec']=[]
myhistory['reca']=[]
myhistory['f1']=[]

class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        predict = numpy.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))
        predict = a=numpy.array(predict.flatten()>=0.5,dtype=int)
        targ = self.validation_data[1]
        targ=numpy.array(targ.flatten()>=0.5,dtype=int)
        self.prf=precision_recall_fscore_support(targ, predict)
        print("Precision/recall/f1 class 0 is {}/{}/{}, precision/recall/f1 class 1 is {}/{}/{}".format(self.prf[0][0], self.prf[1][0], self.prf[2][0], self.prf[0][1], self.prf[1][1], self.prf[2][1]))
        myhistory['prec'].append(self.prf[0][1])
        myhistory['reca'].append(self.prf[1][1])
        myhistory['f1'].append(self.prf[2][1])
        return
metrics = Metrics()
```

Once fitting is finished I display everything on a common plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
precision = [1-x for x in myhistory['prec']]
recall = [1-x for x in myhistory['reca']]
f_one = [1-x for x in myhistory['f1']]

epochs = range(1, len(loss) + 1)

# "bo" is for "blue dot"
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'bo', label='Training loss')
# b is for "solid blue line"
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'b', label='Validation loss')
plt.plot(epochs, precision, 'r', label='One minus precision')
plt.plot(epochs, recall, 'g', label='One minus recall')
plt.plot(epochs, f_one, 'm', label='One minus f1')
plt.title('Training and validation loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I'm using “one minus precision,” etc., to have everything in the range close to zero. What I don't understand though is that, as you can see in the plot,
[image] although validation loss is increasing (due to overfitting), precision, recall seem to vary so that F1 stays relatively constant. What am I doing wrong?

The example is taken from [Chapter 3 of F. Chollet's book](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/deep-learning-with-python/chapter-3), it is about IMDB texts classification and I am only displaying scores for class 1.

Comment: Have you solved your question? How would you calculate it for the training-data? Btw. I dont think setting a threshold is very wise since keras does not use a threshold